# Vertical Flyout menu with CSS for Wordpress theme

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

Sorry, I'm not a professional developer and therefore not in the right place here. I really try to get along with Wordpress and CSS but I couldn't find help regarding one specific problem that's why I reach out to you here: I would like to add a fly-out sub menu on this page: https://mkwtest354675275.wpcomstaging.com/

Could anyone here help me out please? Any advice would be highly appreciated! Thank you so much!

Kind regards, Alena

Comment: Please include any other demo or screenshot/prototype of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Also check this if it can help: https://codepen.io/mdrd88/pen/AcbBH

Answer (score 0):

Add following css for fly-out sub menu in your site (modify as per your need)

```
ul.sub-menu {
    display: none;
}

#menu-hauptmenue li:hover .sub-menu {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: pink;
    top: 1%;
    left: 18%;
    min-width: 200px;
    z-index: 6;
    -webkit-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
    -ms-transition: left 200ms ease-in;
    transition: left 200ms ease-in;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```